# Ruby on Rails: Delete link to redirects to show page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, destroy

I'm working on a rails 5.0 application. It's a legacy application and has been poorly maintained over the years and god knows what hasn't been updated on it properly (for example, its still using a `public/` structure to contain all of its stylesheet and javascript files).

I'm having trouble getting the default rails delete routes to execute.

Consider the following controller action:

```
class Admin::PackagesController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    @package = Package.find(params[:id])
    @package.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url}
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

But when I call the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', ['admin', package], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

It doesn't call the destroy action: it goes to the show action for the individual package.

Comment: Do you see any JS error when clicked on the delete button? Most of the time it happens due to if rails-ujs/jquery-ujs is not configured.. Please check if JS error is there or not.

Comment: You need UJS to make :method => :delete argument working.

Comment: @zasman can you show your rake `routes | grep packages`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still an issue but I ran into it with a Rails 7 blog/comments app. The following code within a 'comment' partial (for Post show page) and a comment controller fix solved the issue for me.

_comment.html.erb:

```
    <%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment], data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'are you sure?' }, class: 'button is-danger' %>
```

comments_controller.rb:

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post), status: :see_other
  end
```

The `status: :see_other` section of the redirect was essential in it working and understanding how Rails handles redirects and this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303) helped a lot!

Answer (score -2):

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', package_path(package), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on why this will solve the problem? A single line of code is a little mysterious.

Comment: Sorry. It's my understanding of a standard way to write a delete link in Rails 5, based on this: https://rubyplus.com/articles/2811-Rails-5-Basics-Delete-Article
Upon thinking more about it, however, I'm not so sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: That's more or less equal to what I have now. The `method: :delete` isn't working.